# How to export a data table as different from the UI in JSF Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a data table which I want to export as different from the UI.

For example, part of my data table is

```
<p:column sortBy="#{phi.patProtein}" width="130">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Pathogen Protein" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText id="patProteinText" value="#{phi.patProtein}" />
    <p:commandLink id="patBtn" value="[+]" type="button" />
    <p:overlayPanel for="patBtn" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true"">
        <h:outputText value="#{phi.patProteinLong}"/>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</p:column>
```

I want to export only the output text (`"#{phi.patProtein}"`) from the column, not the command link (`"[+]"`) and overlay panel. But Primefaces exports everything in column, and not gives me a chance to specify which fields of column to export.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you check the PrimeFaces showcase and documentation at all? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/excludeColumns.xhtml. It is not 100% what your code looks like, but if it works, it works

Comment: Yes, I've checked the documentation multiple times but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Comment: But if you slightly change your code (put the commandbutton in a different colum) it works…

Comment: An alternative approach to using the PrimeFaces DataExporter would be to create the table on the backend directly by fetching the data from the database, gives you greater flexibility to make the exported file, exactly how you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create two `<p:column>`s, one containing the `<h:outputText>` and the other one containing the `<p:commandLink>` and the `<p:overlaypanel>`, you can set the attribute `"exportable"` of the second column to `false`:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{phi.patProtein}" width="130">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Pathogen Protein" />    
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText id="patProteinText" value="#{phi.patProtein}" />
</p:column>
<p:column exportable="false">   
    <p:commandLink id="patBtn" value="[+]" type="button" />
    <p:overlayPanel for="patBtn" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true"">
       <h:outputText value="#{phi.patProteinLong}"/>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</p:column>
```

Then only the text should be exported.

Comment: Thanks. But it is a trivial solution. I don't want to create new columns that change my original UI. Basically, my question is "How can I do this without changing the UI?".

Comment: There's always the way to fiddle with css (columnclasses of dataTable) to make it look the same. Otherwise you would have to mess with the internals of the primefaces components.

Comment: Finally, my problem was solved after doing some css tricks. Although it is not exactly the same with the original UI, it looks good for now. Thanks again.

Comment: @nskarakoc can u give the css code u did to solve this issue. I'm facing similar issue